# updating android sdk doesn't function

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip for Android, to install it on ubuntu 16.04

When I run

```
./bin/sdkmanager --update
```

I starts looking for `package.xml` everywhere on my `HOME` directory which was shocking for me. Why does it look in directories that aren't even  closely related to Android installation ???

Then it found some `package.xml` files (not related to android at all) and printed lots of this kind of errors:

```
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at /home/myuser/backed-up/backups/html/package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
```

And finally, it printed this error:

```
Warning: File /home/myuser/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.         
[=======================================] 100% Computing updates...
```

I quickly touched the file and ran the process again:

```
myuser@host :~/android-tools$ touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg
myuser@host :~/android-tools$ ./bin/sdkmanager --update
```

After about 5 minutes of scanning my 2 TB disk for `package.xml` it exited without any hint of what is wrong.

So, I have 2 questions. How do I stop sdkmanager to look in directories that are outside of ~/android-tools ??  And second: how do I update android tools? it seems that the installation process is completely broken.